# Is there any closed-form solution to $\int \dot{y}\cot (y) dy$

Tags: integration

To solve the following differential equation

$\dfrac{\dot{x}}{x} = \dot{y}\cot (y)$,

I'm wondering there is any closed form for the integral of the RHS, saying,$\displaystyle\int \dot{y}\cot (y) dt$.

Both $x$ and $y$ are functions of an arbitrary variable $t$.

Comment: You should have applied $\int dt$, not $\int dy$.

Comment: @J.G.: fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cot y dy=\frac{dx}{x}$, $\ln x=\int\cot y dy=\ln\sin y+C$, i.e. $x\propto\sin y$.